# SQL query doesn't apply "between" condition correctly

Tags: mysql

I was wondering if my query was correct or not...

```
SELECT mois, idVisiteur, nbJustificatifs, SUM(montantValide), idEtat 
FROM fichefrais WHERE mois BETWEEN 201009 AND 201804 GROUP BY idVisiteur
```

When I execute it, I only get the results where mois=201009, and that's it. I tried with the '', with mois>=201009 and mois<=201804, nothing changes. The table contains 2100+ results, from 201001 to 201804.

mois is a char(6).

Any ideas ? Thanks.
Lucille

Comment: try like  BETWEEN '201009' AND '201804'

if still not work than use two separate where condition  >= and <=

Comment: I think the BETWEEN keyword is not giving you the appropriate result because mois is char. Try changing it to INT or LONG or even DATE (i'm supposing 201009 means September 2010).

Comment: According to [MySQL conversion rules](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/type-conversion.html), it should work both with `mois BETWEEN 201009 AND 201804` (i.e. numbers) and `mois BETWEEN '201009' AND '201804'` (i.e. strings). But, as a general rule, try to not mix the types. Since `mois` is `char(6)`, compare it only with strings.

Comment: Something is missing here. What happens if you exclude GROUP BY from your query? And what happens if you replace SELECT `mois` with something like `SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT mois) AS mois_combined`, for example?

Comment: I changed the type of mois from char to int. Same problem... I tried without the group by condition, I only get one result. With the group_concat, I can actually see all the months on the same line. Progress !

Comment: Okay, okay, now that works ! No idea of what I've done...

Comment: If you are comparing "NUMBERS-LIKE" strings, the most reliable way is to convert to numbers and then compare. Other alternatives may yield the expected results, but their reliability will always be questionable.

Comment: The problem is not about type juggling. Ask yourself: how many rows in your result set should have the same `idVisiteur` value?